# Computation of Cholesky factor

Tags: linear-algebra, algorithms

So the Cholesky decomposition theorem states that 
that any **real symmetric positive-definite** matrix $M$ has a Cholesky decomposition $M= LL^\top$ where $L$ is a lower triangular matrix.

Given $M$, we already know there are fast algorithms to calculate its Cholesky factor $L$.

Now, suppose I was given a rectangular $m\times n$ matrix $A$, and I knew that $A^\top A$ was positive definite. Is there a way to calculate the Cholesky factor $L$ of $A^\top A$ without computing $A^\top A$ explicitly and then applying Cholesky factorization algorithms?

If $A$ is a very large rectangular matrix performing $A^\top A$ explicitly seems very expensive and hence the question.

Comment: More than the expense of forming the cross-product matrix, this approach also squares the condition number of your $\mathbf A$. If your $\mathbf A$ is nearly rank-deficient, then this is certainly a poor way to proceed.

Comment: [This question](http://scicomp.stackexchange.com/questions/7071/efficient-triangularisation-of-mathbfs-operatornametriag-left-mathbfa) and [this question](http://scicomp.stackexchange.com/questions/1101/seemingly-non-unique-cholesky-factor-via-qr-rectangularisation?rq=1) asks the same thing in different ways.  The answers in these threads (and the answers below) should be useful to you.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Yes, you can obtain the factor (up to the signs of entries) using QR decomposition; see [this answer](https://scicomp.stackexchange.com/a/2893/1804). Note that if all you're interested in is solving the least squares problem that lead to the normal equations involving $A^T A$, you can use the QR decomposition directly.

Answer (score 8):

Yes. Compute the $QR$ factorization and take $L=R^T$; rescale the rows of $R$ if necessary (by changing some of their signs) to make the sign of the diagonal nonnegative (as the Cholesky factor is defined to have a nonnegative diagonal).

For sparse QR factorizations see, e.g., 
http://dl.acm.org/citation.cfm?id=174408