# Efficient Triangularisation of $\mathbf{S} = \operatorname{triag}\left(\mathbf{A}\right)$ ; $\mathbf{S}\mathbf{S}^T = \mathbf{A} \mathbf{A}^T$

Tags: linear-algebra

The most computationally intensive part of my application is the triangularisation of a matrix, $\mathbf{S} = \operatorname{triag}\left(\mathbf{A}\right)$, such that $\mathbf{S}\mathbf{S}^T = \mathbf{A} \mathbf{A}^T$.

For this application $\mathbf{A} \in \Re^{n \times 2(n+v)}$, where $n$ is generally close to the same value as $v$.

Currently, I solve via a QR decomposition, $\mathbf{A}^T = \mathbf{Q} \mathbf{R}$:

$\mathbf{A} \mathbf{A}^T = (\mathbf{R}^T \mathbf{Q}^T) (\mathbf{Q} \mathbf{R})$

$   = \mathbf{R}^T \mathbf{Q}^T \mathbf{Q} \mathbf{R}       $

$   = \mathbf{R}^T \mathbf{R}$

$   = \mathbf{S} \mathbf{S}^T$

Which gives the form that I want.

Is there a more efficient way to perform this operation?  Even a modest saving over QR will provide a performance boost as this one operation is profiled as 30% of my total computing time.

---

The $\operatorname{triag}()$ function is the heart of the [Divided Difference Filter](https://dl.acm.org/doi/10.1016/S0005-1098(00)00089-3), which is similar to the more commonly known [Unscented Kalman Filter](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kalman_filter#Unscented_Kalman_filter).  The problem is mentioned explicitly in the paper that introduces the [Cubature Kalman Filter](https://ieeexplore.ieee.org/document/4982682).

In short, it calculates four "divided difference" matrices, based on the non-linear process model and state covariance Cholesky factors.  These four matrices are horizontally concatenated, and then triangularised - this forms the predicted state covariance:

$ \mathbf{S}(k+1|k) = \operatorname{triag}\left(\begin{bmatrix} 
            \mathbf{S}_{xx}^{(2)} & \mathbf{S}_{xv}^{(1)} & \mathbf{S}_{xx}^{(2)} & \mathbf{S}_{xv}^{(2)} \end{bmatrix} \right)$

where $\mathbf{S}_{pq}^n$ above are the "divided difference" matrices calculated above.  The predicted state covariance Cholesy factor $\mathbf{S}(k+1|k)$ is then directly used to generate "divided difference" matrices of the predicted measurements.

A similar process follows of triangularisation of the predicted measurements, but as my measurement vector is small compared to my state vector, this calculation (and the subsequent Kalman Gain/Update) equations are not computationally intensive (about 4% of the process time).

Comment: What is your ultimate speed goal? Suppose you could cut the QR time in half, then you'd only be saving 15% CPU time. Is that really enough to achieve what you hope to achieve?

Comment: @MichaelC.Grant, the algorithm runs on a real-time embedded system where the filter must compete with plenty of other processes.  There is no option to "throw more hardware at the problem" as there is a substantial install base.  Any real CPU saving (even if only a couple of percent) gives us options, whether it be for more advanced algorithms or more features elsewhere in the system.  Or, we'll simply claim the CPU for a latency reduction, which is a worthy goal in and of itself.

Comment: Fair enough. Then I'm going to cast my lot with Brian's answer below. If you think $AA^T$ will be reasonably well conditioned, then it might save you some cycles to compute its Cholesky factor.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

If $AA^{T}$ is well conditioned, then you might be able to get away with using the Cholesky factorization of $AA^{T}$ rather than using the QR factorization.  Depending on the size of $A$ this could be vastly faster than computing the QR factorization of $A$.  If you told us something about the size of $A$ we could address that question.

However, if $AA^{T}$ is badly conditioned, then using the Cholesky factorization could be a bad idea because the Cholesky factorization will be less accurate.  It would help to know something about the condition number of $AA^{T}$.

You haven't told us why you want $S$ and what you do with it after computing this factorization.  It's quite possible that there's a much more efficient way to solve the higher level problem without ever computing this factorization of $AA^{T}$.  However, we can't make any suggestions unless you provide more background on what you're trying to accomplish.   In other words, a good answer to this question is going to depend on a lot of context that you haven't provided yet.

Comment: I'll update my question shortly.